# Matplotlib multiple plots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to take a few variables, x1,x2,x3 and print a simple plot of how they interact with my variable y.

Near as I can tell, it's hard to make a plt object? That is, I can't run a loop like:

```
for x in listOfX:
   plt.scatter(x,y)
   plt.show()
```

It doesn't appear to clear the plt object as I change X.

Comment: Can you include some sample data?

Comment: you should do ```plt.figure()``` before each ```plt.scatter()```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after here, but I think this will help.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':1000, 'ID':'123'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'123'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':2000, 'ID':'123'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'456'},
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'ID':'456'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':10000, 'ID':'456'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'ID':'789'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':2000, 'ID':'789'},
       {'Month': '2020-05-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'789'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':1000, 'ID':'123'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'123'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':2000, 'ID':'123'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-01-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'456'},
       {'Month': '2020-02-01', 'Expense':5000, 'ID':'456'}, 
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':10000, 'ID':'456'},
       {'Month': '2020-03-01', 'Expense':5000, 'ID':'789'},
       {'Month': '2020-04-01', 'Expense':2000, 'ID':'789'},
       {'Month': '2020-05-01', 'Expense':3000, 'ID':'789'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

```
uniques = df['ID'].unique()

for i in uniques:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(4,3)
    df_single = df[df['ID']==i]
    sns.lineplot(data=df_single, x='Month', y='Expense')
    ax.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Total Expense')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.show()
```

[image]